# Update Template description using Python SDK for Smarsheet API

Tags: smartsheet-api

Asking with hopefulness.

Is there are way to update the Template Description either directly or using the Python SDK?

I'm guessing "no" since the only way to see the Template Description after creation is via the API (can not via the GUI).

-Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the template endpoints are read-only.